# Where clause to retrieve all users

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm just getting started with Firebase.  My problem is about the 'where' clause.

I got some data (json):

```
Users
|
|_____ John
|        |___ name: John Farmer
|        |___ searchingForGame: true
|
|_____ James
|        |___ name: James Smith
|        |___ searchingForGame: false
|
|_____ Barbara
         |___ name: Barbara Smith
         |___ searchingForGame: true
```

I want to retrieve all Users `WHERE searchingForGame = true`.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show some effort before posting an question :)

Comment: Something like `ref.orderByChild('searchingForGame').equalTo(true).on(...`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: Thx, I can use that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not work like SQL, you need totally different way to approach it. I sincerely recommend reading through their documentation first, it's very good! This link should answer at least part of your question: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html